# JUnit Assert#assertSame equivalent in Hamcrest

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, instance, hamcrest

Is there an equivalent in hamcrest library for JUnit's `Assert#assertSame`? If yes, what is it? At the moment I can only think of [`Hamcrest#sameInstance`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#sameInstance%28T%29) but I am not quite sure this method is the right one to use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The underlying matcher that provides this functionality is [`org.hamcrest.core.IsSame`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/core/IsSame.html). It has convenience methods to hide it both in [`org.hamcrest.Matchers#sameInstance`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#sameInstance%28T%29) (as you mentioned) and in [`org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers#sameInstance`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/CoreMatchers.html#sameInstance%28T%29).

Whichever you use is mainly a preference issue. Personally, I prefer statically importing from `CoreMatchers`, just because it's "slimmer":

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.sameInstance;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import org.junit.Test;

public class SomeTest {
    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        Object o1 = new Object();
        Object o2 = o1;

        assertThat(o1, sameInstance(o2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to turn to

```
assertThat(actual, isSame(expected))
```

here.

Comment: Having static import `org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;` I see *can not resolve method isSame*. What shall I import then?

Comment: You need the CoreMatchers.